# Warn that editing questions in the Close Votes review queue will dismiss it from the queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, edits, vote-to-close

Editing a question in the Close Votes review has a rather unexpected consequence: the question is immediately removed from the queue. I'm pretty certain that not all people noticed this. See for example [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3628303) of an [obviously bad question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698792/how-to-retrieve-object-from-db-by-current-field): it received three close votes and then somebody went in an edited a typo in the question title, with the effect of removing the question from the queue (*note*: that question was improved later).

I think people should be warned about the consequences, with a message like: "Please only edit questions that you think should *not* be closed after your changes."

For reference:

- [Why does an Edit action kick a post out of the Close Votes queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162034/why-does-an-edit-action-kick-a-post-out-of-the-close-votes-queue)
- [Let me edit a post in the close review, then vote to close it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169988/let-me-edit-a-post-in-the-close-review-then-vote-to-close-it)

Comment: Should this be shown only to people editing from the review queue, or to anone that can see close votes and is trying to edit a post?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Simply editing the post doesn't remove it from the queue, only doing that from the review queue does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make it simple and change the button's label to "Edit & Leave Open". That way there's no need for extra popups or reading some descriptions hidden under a "(more)" link, and it will be dead obvious what the action behind the button *really* is.

Comment: more accurate description of this action would be like _"Edit & Abort Review"_ - because edit does more than just Leave Open vote - it aborts review

Comment: @gnat: IMHO you don't need that level of detail (see the post by Shog9 explaining why). It's sufficient to make obvious that this is an action towards leaving the question open.

Answer (score 11):

There's already *some* guidance to this effect in the close review queue itself:

[image: Edit if this question could be improved so that it does not need to be closed]

It doesn't explicitly call out the effect that editing will have on the disposition of review item itself, but *none* of the action descriptions do - in practice, this has been subject to change even when the actions themselves (and the guidance given for them) haven't; the hope is that folks will Do The Right Thing for the post they're reviewing, without *worrying* about what will happen to it after that.

That said, we're always open to suggestions for improvement - if you think you can improve on the guidance given to reviewers, post your ideas.

Comment: These guidelines are way too much text, you cannot expect everybody to read these properly. I think that the solution by 3ventic is a better one - extremely short and hard to miss.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like this — a warning, or the [Edit and Leave Open] button, or even to have [Edit] *not* do anything to the post's place in the queue.

I've been using this network for about seven years and been a heavy editor for five, and I've had *no idea* the Edit button in the close queue did that. I've even used the Edit button a couple of times on a site where I've also been a diamond moderator, on reviews that probably should've stayed in the queue. I've used it to make tangential edits that don't resolve the problem, and wouldn't have done so if the button was labelled [Edit and Leave Open].

I only found out about this recently: someone pinged me in a comment to tell me what the Edit review option I'd picked had done, so I went looking for documentation that could verify that for me and tell me more, and that trail's lead me to this feature request.

Answer (score 5):

Such a warning now exists; it was implemented as part of the review queue enhancements last month to add descriptions for each review item:

[image: "Improve this question yourself and keep it open."]

That said, the review action has been [changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315946/allow-suggesting-edits-in-the-close-votes-review-queue-on-beta-sites/370652#370652) so that the "Edit" button is no longer a binding action, and now counts the same as a standard review to leave open (meaning the review task will only be dismissed with an outcome of leaving open if two other users agree that it should be left open).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good idea, but could be implemented in a bit different way. There could be a new dialog after editing a question in the Close Vote Queue that says something to this effect:

> Since you edited this question, do you think it should still be closed?

That way, if a problematic question that *isn't* off-topic after editing, it can be kicked out of the queue, and if it *is* still off-topic it can stay in the queue and possibly recieve another close vote from saying yes to this dialog.

Comment: Maybe we can follow that up with a third dialog that just rants at the editor for wasting time on a question they think should be closed.

Comment: Editing a question without improving it substantially indeed sounds like wasting everybody's time. Either way, your suggestion is what [Let me edit a post in the close review, then vote to close it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169988/163275) is about and it has been sitting around since March (now it's even declined). Implementing a warning is much simpler and should be less controversial.

Comment: @9Shogsa-Shogging That's true, but then again, why is the edit button even shown in the CV queue anyway?

Comment: @WladimirPalant Do you really think people will read that?

Comment: @hichris123: see [my answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162034/why-does-an-edit-action-kick-a-post-out-of-the-close-votes-queue/162058#162058) for a fairly detailed explanation. For a short summary, click the "(more)" link *in the close review queue*.

Comment: @9Shogsa-Shogging I'm not a 3K user yet, so I can't look at the CV queue guidelines, but I'm just making suggestions on my (limited) experience.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212862/warn-about-editing-questions-in-the-close-votes-review-queue/214848#214848)

Answer (score 0):

I would say, Edit and leave open is a great option,

However, this should also go back into the close votes with all those who voted to get an opportunity to change their vote if appropriate.

Maybe a message at the top of the Review Que saying:

> [Question] was edited, please re-confirm if it should be closed

<sub>^ The wording isn't great, please edit it!</sub>