# Allow suggesting edits in the Close Votes review queue on beta sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, beta-sites

On Beta sites, you get the Close/Reopen privilege at 500 reputation, *before* the Edit privilege (1000 reputation). This means that the Edit button, which is normally visible in the Close Votes review queue on designed sites (where the closing privilege is earned *after* the editing privilege):

[image: "Close Votes" review queue button selection on a site where the user has both closure and edit privileges; in order, the buttons are "Leave Open", "Close", "Edit", and "Skip"]

...is hidden on beta and non-designed sites:

[image: "Close Votes" review queue button selection on a site where the user has closure but not edit privileges; in order, the buttons are "Leave Open", "Close", and "Skip"]

...if the user has enough rep to vote to close, but not enough to edit.

However, in the Reopen Votes review queue, there *is* an Edit option:

[image: "Reopen Votes" review queue button selection on a site where the user has closure but not edit privileges; in order, the buttons are "Leave Closed", "Edit and Reopen", "Reopen", and "Skip"]

Since it's just as important to edit a question to save it from being closed, as it is to edit it to get it reopened, can we enable the Edit button in the Close Votes review queue as well, even if the reviewer doesn't have editing privileges?

Comment: Can anyone provide history or an explanation as to why the order of those privileges is different for beta sites? It's not intuitive to me.

Comment: @WillCain Sonic [just posted a question about that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315947/295232).

Comment: What does "…designed…" and "…non-designed sites:…" mean? I realize this was added by a different user but maybe you understand? I would place the screen images in block quotes, it would look less confusing.

Comment: Sites which have graduated but did not receive a custom design yet. Examples: [codegolf.se], [philosophy.se], [anime.se].

Comment: ^ those are non-designed, non-beta sites. They still have the privilege levels of a beta site.

Comment: Folks, _please_ don't remove tags just for the sake of making room for a status tag, we'll do that when (or if) we add one. Thanks!

Comment: While I understand wanting to have parity with the non-beta sites, the "Edit" button in review queues, *as a review response*, is broken. Primarily it's used to fix trivial formatting issues with the post. While fixing such things is normally good, the *bad thing* is that an "Edit" response in a review queue removes the post from the review queue. IME, it's very rare for the edits performed there to actually resolve the underlying problems with the post (i.e. the post should not be kicked out of the queue). If just the normal post "edit" button was enabled, that would be good.

Comment: I've thought about this for a while, and this may not make sense as written. The Edit action, as @Makyen pointed out, counts as a binding Leave Open review, and if this is implemented as written, this would allow the task to be completed just by submitting a suggested edit. What if said suggested edit is rejected, though? The question will still (probably) be in a closeable state. I think the best thing is to not have edit suggestions count as a binding Leave Open review, but as a *single* such review, or not count toward that count.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Going forward, all users who can participate in the Close Votes queue will see an Edit action on the tasks. Users with full edit rights will be able to make the edits just as before, while users who are only able to suggest edits will be  submitting suggested edits instead.

As part of this change, we are also starting to count "Edit" reviews the same way we count "Leave open" ones: each Close Votes review task will need to reach the required review threshold with a combination of "Edit" and "Leave open" reviews. (The old behavior was that only "Leave open" reviews counted towards that threshold, but "Edit" reviews resolved the task immediately.)

Comment: I've edited [the canonical list as to how review tasks are dismissed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-review-task-completed-or-invalidated) with this change. Can you please confirm that the rest of the post is correct?

Comment: You might want to give [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212862/warn-about-editing-questions-in-the-close-votes-review-queue) a status tag, due to the new text as well as this new behavior.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks, done! And I'll take a look at the list of how tasks are dismissed next week.

Answer (score 6):

We are in the middle of a project to update our Review Queues and will dive deeper into this request as part of this project. Can't guarantee that we will implement this particular suggestion, but we will absolutely consider it and update this ticket when we are further along.