# Review queue Help Center draft: Late answers queue

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, review, announcements, help-center-proposed

This post is part of a larger effort to [create Help Center pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356120/creating-new-help-center-documents-for-review-queues-project-overview) for each of the Review queues. You can learn more about this project in the overview post. These posts will be locked so that everyone has a chance to review each original draft and provide feedback in the answers. We will continue to collect feedback until **November 9th, 2020**.

We are looking for your feedback on this draft for the **Late answers queue**.
When reviewing this draft please consider the following:

- What is essential to know about using this queue?
- Is there any information that’s missing or should be removed?

> ## How do I use the Late Answers queue?
>
> *Access earned at $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation*
> The Late Answers queue contains answers which were posted by new users much
> later than when the question was asked. Late answers tend to be seen
> by fewer people than answers posted soon after the question was asked,
> so the review queue helps ensure that these answers meet the same
> quality standards as all other answers.
>
> While many late answers are merely saying “Thanks!” or are attempts to
> ask follow-up questions and should be deleted, in other cases it may
> require specific knowledge of the topic - if you’re unsure whether the
> answer actually attempts to answer the question, use the “Skip”
> option.
>
> ### Basic workflow
>
> When reviewing, you may do one or more of several actions or you may do none. Perform all actions that you deem
> necessary - for example an answer may be complete and do a good job of
> answering the question but need formatting help. In this case, edit to
> improve the formatting and - if you wish - upvote it before clicking "I'm done".
>
> - Choose **No action needed** if the answer requires no intervention
> - Select **I’m done** if/when
>   you’ve completed any of the following:
>
>   - **Vote** up or down
>   - **Edit** (or
>     suggest an edit) if the answer is clear and within guidelines but
>     could use some editing help to improve grammar, spelling, or
>     formatting
>   - **Comment** to point out content that is missing or may need
>     adjusting. These comments can be useful to both the post author and
>     other reviewers.
>   - **Flag** posts that are spam or rude as well as answers that don't attempt to answer the question or are link-only.
>   - [Trusted users](/help/privileges/trusted-user) may also **Delete** answers that don’t attempt to answer the question, are
>     link-only, or are duplicates of other answers.
> - **Skip** if you’re unsure about what to do
>
> ### Common Late answers
>
> - Spam or self-promotion
>
>   - If the answer meets the [description for acceptable self-promotion](/help/promotion), add a
>     comment mentioning this to reduce the chance of other reviewers
>     marking it spam. If it does not, add a comment linking to the help
>     center article and encourage the author to edit the post to meet our
>     guidelines. If it unequivocally looks like spam, flag it as such.
> - Non-answers
>
>   - Answers thanking the author of the question or one of its
>     answers, asking a new question, stating that they have the same problem, or asking for clarification from the author. These should be deleted.
>
> For more information on how to edit effectively, please see our [Help Center article about editing](/help/editing).
>
> Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
> [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031), which also contains more in-depth
> guidance if you are interested in reading more about this queue.

### Other drafts

To review other drafts in part of this project, please see below:

- [Review queue Help Center draft: Close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356121/review-queue-help-center-draft-close-votes)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356126/review-queue-help-center-draft-reopen-votes-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Low-quality posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356127/review-queue-help-center-draft-low-quality-posts-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356125/review-queue-help-center-draft-suggested-edits-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: First posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356122/review-queue-help-center-draft-first-posts-queue)
- Review queue Help Center draft: Late answers (this post)

Stack overflow only:

- [Review queue Help Center draft: Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402611/review-queue-help-center-draft-triage-queue)
- [Review queue Help Center draft: Help & improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402612/review-queue-help-center-draft-help-improvement-queue)

Answer (score 6):

> **Delete** (or recommend deletion of) answers that don’t attempt to answer the question, are link-only, or are duplicates of other answers.

You can't recommend deletion in the Late Answers queue if you lack the reputation to delete answers; instead, you should flag answers (as NAA or VLQ) which qualify for deletion. (On sites where I *am* able to vote to delete such answers, I still flag, to trigger the Low Quality Posts review queue.)

Comment: So... is "delete" an option that does more harm than good? If the correct action is to flag, should we drop delete as an option at all? There's so many options on late answers and first posts that getting rid of some of them isn't a terrible thing.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the correct action (if you have the privileges) is to flag *and* vote to delete.

Comment: More in line with what you're thinking?

Answer (score 5):

> Posts thanking the author of the question or one of its answers, asking a new question, or asking for clarification from the author. These should be deleted.

Another very common reason (enough to warrant a canned comment in the Low quality posts review queue) is answerers having the same problem as the author of the question. Depending on the site, it might be even more common than the reasons mentioned here, so IMHO it deserves a spot in the new Help Center page.

Comment: Added. This is one I do see a lot, so good point.