# Editing in review queues other than suggested edits automatically rejects the pending edits

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

Whenever I review Low Quality Posts (or any other posts), I see an "Edit" button. When I click on that button I'm able to edit the post even if there's a proposed edit pending. When the post is edited from queue it automatically rejects the pending edit as "*This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.*".

For example, [this post](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/967321) was in Low Quality Posts Queue. Then [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/) clicked on the "Edit" button, submitted and edit from there, and the pending [suggested edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/967316) was rejected automatically. I discussed this with [Eliah in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51233210#51233210) and I think that it's a bug.

I think the review page should check if there's pending edit or not or at least redirect to "Suggested Edit" page if there's any. Since in my opinion, this wastes the time and efforts of <2000 reputation users and it may happen that the editor made better improvement than the reviewer.

Comment: I've asked about the same problem, but different queues and solution: [Show that there's a pending suggested edit in the Close/Reopen Votes review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328043/295232)

Comment: Very similar ... but my question (and the answer) focus on the Close and Reopen queues, yours on the LQP. Yours is a bug, mine a feature request. I think it's fine to leave it open for now - a CM or developer from Stack Exchange will look at this and can then decide whether they're duplicate enough.