# Prevent starting to suggest an edit from the First Posts review queue if there is already a pending edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

Clicking the 'edit' link if there is a pending edit results in an error message:

[image]

However, that message does not appear if you click the 'edit' link from the First Posts review queue. It only appears when you try to submit the edit:

[image]

Comment: Related, but I don’t think it’s a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91547/reject-edit-suggestions-on-old-revisions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should now be fixed with the release of the ["pending edit" notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370653/155160) that replaces the edit action.

No way to start an edit, no problem. :)

Answer (score 5):

Haven't had a developer look at this specifically, but we should be able to fix this bug within the next few weeks as part of the final leg of our Review Queues revamp. Just marked this [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned).