# Make it clear in the moderator tools when a delete vote is retracted

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, vote-to-delete, timeline

(Origin of this request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371277/253521)

Users can now retract delete votes. Moderators can also see a second date entry on the timeline for retracted votes. However, it's not clear that the second date is indicating the date/time that the user retracted their delete vote. For example:

[image: screenshot of timeline showing moderator view of delete vote and delete vote retraction by me, TylerH]

As you can see, there are two dates shown here for a delete vote by me:

- 2 days ago
- yesterday

But it is not immediately clear why there are two. It would probably help moderators during investigations, etc. if the column showing what kind of vote was performed indicated that the delete vote was retracted on the row showing the second date (yesterday in this example), e.g.:

[image: same example as above, except this time showing a line item explaining the action was the removal of a delete vote]

(NB - Because this information is only visible to moderators or staff, a Stack Overflow moderator provided the screenshot above at my request; I am not a moderator anywhere)

Comment: @tinkeringbell This data is only visible to moderators, so '10k tools' would be an inaccurate tag. 10k users cannot see any secondary date for when they retract their delete votes.

Comment: The timeline isn't a mod-exclusive tool though.. and delete votes are a 10k tool, and retracting them is a 10k thing too as mod delete votes are binding... luckily, there's always room for one more then? :D

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Well, there is room for 5 yes, but I was trying to leave space for when Felippe sees it and marks it as status-deferred or status-planned without having to choose one to remove...

Comment: I struggled with a way to make it clear in the title that this feature is only useful to moderators because it's only visible to them, so I opted for just using the tag instead. If you can think of a clearer/more descriptive title, please edit it!

Comment: Do we show something when you retract close votes or is it the same? If not, this seems like a bigger request - "Show 'retracted' in timeline for retracted delete/undelete/close/reopen" votes.... the behavior is the same as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Well you can always fumble in a 'for moderators' :P As for the tags, I wouldn't worry too much about it... I think [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315946/allow-suggesting-edits-in-the-close-votes-review-queue-on-beta-sites#comment1041703_315946) applies to leaving things out as well ;)

Comment: @Catija The timeline of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/340530/timeline) shows a retracted close vote... it's marked as 'cleared', by Community, with a timestamp that's about 7 minutes earlier than the actual closing of the post :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Thanks - :) I definitely see some other places where we don't show a resolution, but they're not all public, either - some may be staff only (e.g. bookmarks, I think?)...

Comment: @Catija Yeah, I can't see bookmarks in the timeline so that's definitely staff only :)

Comment: @Catija For normal users, retracted close votes still show in their Votes tab.

Comment: @bad_coder your edit introduced a typo; it's currently correct without the "and". I've rewritten the sentence entirely.

Comment: @Catija If you want to pick a post for guinea pigging here, maybe Tinkerbell and I can take a screenshot each to show what is visible to mods (Tink could share in the TL perhaps, or manually redact as necessary) and 10k users, vs staff

Comment: To add some context, there's nothing in that entry for the **vote** that indicates it was retracted. Previously, you only saw the second date when the delete vote was successful (and the public entry about deletion was made, which "ties" the vote dates together for clarity). It wasn't obvious why that vote, in isolation, had the second date (or the coloring it did). It would be nice if it says "retracted" (or something to that effect) elsewhere