# Remove "edit and reopen" for low rep users on metas with "beta" privileges

Tags: bug, review, privileges, per-site-meta, vote-to-reopen

On a child meta, when a user has the privilege to vote to close/reopen but not edit freely, they still have the option to "Edit and reopen", change whatever on the "edit question" page, and then be blocked from actually submitting the edit. There really shouldn't be an inaccessible option like this.

[image: please select one… leave closed, edit and reopen, reopen]

This happens most often with "beta" privilege levels, since voting to reopen is 500 rep and editing is 1k, but it can also with similar custom rep levels. (I was on Webapps, with 500 rep to vote to reopen and 2k for editing.)

Comment: Since when did these edits start to be blocked? It used to be that it'd submit a suggested edit.

Comment: In this exact same case, the button used to be hidden for the close queue, but later on [the ability to suggest edits in that queue was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370652/377214).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog On a child meta? Aren't you thinking of the main site?

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't see the part where you were referring to per-site metas.