# How to both edit and close in the Review queue?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, vote-to-close, design

Quite often I come across questions that need both editing and closure.  When this is from the Review Queue as soon as I am done editing (or closing) the queue jumps to the next question, so if I want to do both I either have to find the question again, or I had to have the foresight to open a copy in a new tab so I can complete the review process.

What is standard procedure for both editing and closing a question in the Review Queue?

If there is nothing easier than what I am doing I shall turn this into a feature request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the question in a new tab to edit, then vote to close in the review queue.

A quick middle mouse click or holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on the keyboard (<kbd>⌘</kbd> on Mac) while clicking on the `link` link or post title suffices to open the post in a new tab.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now but I find it quite awkward.  Assuming this is presently the best way I wish to turn this question into a feature request.  Given that you have already answered are you OK with that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: See [Let me edit a post in the close review, then vote to close it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169988); you'd be a dupe.

Comment: Despite searching I failed to find that duplicate.  I think we should vote to close this as a duplicate of that, though I'm disheartened to see status-declined.