# Make Close Review queue "Edit" button more explicit, something like "Edit and leave open" or maybe "fix"?

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

This is probably an operative request about [Shog9 suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214827/213575) of renaming the Edit button ***in the Review Close Queue***.

Most people are unaware of the functionality of the "Edit" button, beyond that allows them *to edit* the question. This isn't true, as the "Edit" actually means "I fixed all the issues that made this post unfit for the site, hence it shouldn't be in the queue". People unaware of this, do minuscules and irrelevant edits that doesn't correct the status of the post (capitalizing i's and the like) and in some cases they also want to vote to close it despite the correction.

Can the button be more clear about what action it does?